# Moving from GTK to Qt

Tags: python, gtk, pyqt

I have a small application written in python that I want to move from GTK+ to Qt.

The graphics interface in the GTK version is basically a tab widget (gtk.Notebook) that fills the whole top level window. The tab window grows and shrinks with the top level window and fills it completely.

In GTK the code looks like:

```
...
self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
...
self.notebook = gtk.Notebook()
self.window.add(self.notebook)
...
```

How to do something similar in Qt? I just can't figure it out! For the GTK code I used no graphics tool, but now I'm trying to use Qt designer.

JW

Comment: I would suggest reading a tutorial on Qt Designer, but I'm guessing the step you are missing is that, after placing a Tab Widget inside the widget/mainwindow in Qt Designer, you need to right click on an empty portion of the widget and select layout -> layout vertically. That will make it fill up the whole screen. Similarly you need to do the same when placing items in the tabs of the tab widget. This is because QWidget, QMainWindow, etc, come with inbuilt layouts so you don't have to explicitly make your own in those cases

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would get a basic QTabWidget set up:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import (Qt, SIGNAL)
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QDialog,
        QVBoxLayout, QPushButton,  QTabWidget, QWidget, )

class Form(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tabauto = QWidget() #set up 'auto' tab
        self.tabman = QWidget() #set up 'manual' tab
        self.tabs = QTabWidget() #set up tabs widget

        self.ButtonM = QPushButton("Manual Button")
        self.ButtonA = QPushButton("AUto Button")

        layoutO = QVBoxLayout() #set overal layout

        layoutA = QVBoxLayout()
        layoutA.addWidget(self.ButtonA)

        layoutM = QVBoxLayout()
        layoutM.addWidget(self.ButtonM)

        self.tabman.setLayout(layoutM) #Add manual layout to manual tab
        self.tabauto.setLayout(layoutA) #Add automatic layout to automatic tab
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tabauto, "Auto") #assign tabs with their layouts to the overall tab widget
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tabman, "Manual") #assign tabs with their layouts to the overall tab widget
        layoutO.addWidget(self.tabs) #add overall tab widget to overall layout
        self.setLayout(layoutO) #make the overall layout visible

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```